# POST data being cut short

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, post

It seems when I .post() a large array a lot of the information gets removed. In the following code snippet the first .html() shows all the array data while the return result of the PHP only shows a portion of the data.

JavaScript:

```
$('.inner').html(JSON.stringify(dbData));
$.post( "test.php", {'filename' : filename, 'dbData' : dbData}, function(result) {
         $('.inner').html(result);
});
```

PHP:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$dbData = $_POST['dbData'];

$file = $myfile = fopen($filename, 'w');

echo json_encode($dbData);
```

The php.ini has post_max_size = 8M and the data I'm sending through is a lot less than 8M.

EDIT: Data in the array seems to be cut off after a certain point. There are no errors.

Comment: This is probably because the data is larger than `post_max_size` in your php.ini file. You could also check your `max_upload_size` configuration. Another approach would be to check the error log and see if you can spot the problem from there. Also, make sure so you're are looking at the correct `php.ini` file (you might have more than one). You should also notice that after you modify any setting in `php.ini` you'll need to restart your webserver for the changes to take effect.

Comment: What is the error that is generated when you post? You have nothing to check that those POST elements exist. `$filename = isset($_POST['filename'])?$_POST['filename']:""; $dbData = isset($_POST['dbData'])?$_POST['dbData']:""; if(!empty($filename) && !empty($dbData)) { ... }`

Comment: There is no error, entire values of the array are just missing,

Comment: @FuzzyStatic, what are the next two characters after the cutoff? And what is the length of the data getting through?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try increasing the value of `max_input_vars`. I believe the default is 1000.

I've run into this problem a few times where a form is produced with one or more fields for every row in a database table, and when it grows to several hundred rows, the later form fields get chopped off.

Although you only appear to be using one POST var for this, `$_POST['dbData']`, if the AJAX request is sending each each element of dbData as a separate `&dbData[]=...` param, that would be counted many times over.